Ubuntu 24.04 graphics fail to load after few boot ups on Ryzen 5 5500GT based system
I have a AMD based system with Ryzen 5 5500GT with onboard Radeon Graphics. Ubuntu 24.04 GUI based installation works fine, with support for proprietary drivers enabled during installation. Updates and upgrades are applied from time to time, as and when new software is installed.
However after some time (about 20 boot ups) the system fails to display graphics. Boot up messages stop after start of gdm and the system appears to be stuck.  However text console (Ctl+Alt+F2) is working fine. Afterwards, it is impossible to get the graphics back. Also, startx won't work.
Great if someone can suggest any workarounds to this problem.
